# Rolling 7 days Sum with multiple dimensions in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have data like below and want to get (1) today's user numbers and (2) past 7 days' user numbers by the dimensions below. My query isn't returning the result I want. Can someone fix my Hive SQL code?

e.g.) today = 8/9/2018

past 7 days = 8/2/2018 - 8/8/2018

> Dimension: date, website, country_id, product_id
>
> Metrics : user

```
SELECT 
             date, 
             website,
             country_id,
             product_id,
             SUM(user) AS today_users,
             SUM(user) OVER (
           PARTITION BY website, country_id, product_id 
           ORDER BY date ASC ROWS BETWEEN 8 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) as past_7D_users
           FROM  Table
    GROUP BY 
    date, website, country_id, product_id;
```

RawData:

```
    >t_date  |website |country_id|product_id|users
    >8/1/2018   Whatev.com  2     EFG        12 
    >8/2/2018   Whatev.com  2     EFG        23
    >8/3/2018   Whatev.com  2     EFG        34 
    >8/4/2018   Whatev.com  2     EFG        13
    >8/5/2018   Whatev.com  2     EFG        47 
    >8/6/2018   Whatev.com  2     EFG        39
    >8/7/2018   Whatev.com  2     EFG        17 
    >8/8/2018   Whatev.com  2     EFG        34
    >8/1/2018   Google.com  1     ABC        10 
    >8/2/2018   Google.com  1     ABC        20
    >8/3/2018   Google.com  1     ABC        30 
    >8/4/2018   Google.com  1     ABC        14
    >8/5/2018   Google.com  1     ABC        40 
    >8/6/2018   Google.com  1     ABC        35
    >8/7/2018   Google.com  1     ABC        15 
    >8/8/2018   Google.com  1     ABC        32
```

Expected Outcome:

```
date      | website  |country_id|product_id|today_users|past_7D_users|
2018-08-08|Google.com|   1      | ABC      | 32        |164          |
2018-08-09|Whatev.com|   2      | EFG      | 34        |185          |
```

Comment: please post the current output and some sample data..I am guessing the windowing clause should be `ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING`

Comment: Thanks! I added sample data. For this sample data my query works fine (fixed to 7 PRECEDING), but my actual data is very big and doesnt work this way.. :(

Answer (score 1):

Ok.. It's weird to self-answer my question, but I found a workaround. If anyone knows a better, simplified query please share.

```
SELECT x.date
,x.website
,x.country_id
,x.product_id
,x.today_users
,SUM(x.today_users) OVER (PARTITION BY x.website, x.country_id, x.product_id
                          ORDER BY x.date ASC ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS Past_7D_Users

FROM (SELECT 
             date, 
             website,
             country_id,
             product_id,
             SUM(user) AS today_users

    FROM  Table
    GROUP BY 
    date, website, country_id, product_id
)x
GROUP BY x.date
,x.website
,x.country_id
,x.product_id
,x.today_users
;
```